# How to encode txt.value

Tags: javascript

I am passing a string to a javascript through call by reference. The string is a text retrieved from a textarea field. The problem is that a single word is retrieved properly, but when i send multiple text it shows a problem. the sample code is like this in an html file:

```
<input type=button onclick="send(txt.value,123,456)">
```

How to encode txt.value in this case

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what send expects.
generally speaking since it looks like you are calling a function you don't need any encoding.

maybe if you will provide some more code we can better help you.

Comment: IMHO perhaps this should have been a comment on the question? It's not a solution to the problem, regardless of how vaguely the problem is described.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. The problem is when I send a string such as "hello" it is retrieved properly but whenever I send the string as "hello world" the string is not retrieved. It displays nothing

Comment: @Bazz I disagree, he asked how he should encode txt.value - and my answer was that he does not need to encode it sine he is sending it to a function called send. @Sanket, I doubt that anyone will be able to provide more help unless you show more code. nothing in the code that you showed should be affected by the number of words in the string. perhaps the required encoding is in a later step (probably within the send function, this is most likely the place when you WILL need some encoding but we need to see the code for send in order to provide more help.).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text="First"></asp:TextBox><br />
<input type="button" onclick="send(document.getElementById('txtFirst').value,123,456)" value="Click">
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function send(txtValue,obj1,obj2)
{
    alert(txtValue);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `txt.value` is IE only code. Use `document.getElementById` which is cross browser.

Second, the concept itself is working ([proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/uRFAH/)) so something else in your code is causing the problem.

Post your **real** code and the full function and we'll see.

Answer (score -1):

A textarea tag is not a simple input, so you can't get its "value" from txt.value.  You have to get what is between the tags.  Personally I do this with Jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>


function doSend()
{
    var txtvalue=$('#textareaID').text();
    send(txtvalue,123,456);
}

<input type=button onclick="doSend">
```

Comment: download jquery and put it somewhere you can link to it.  In your page, put an id="stextareaID" in your textarea.  If you can't modify the html, read http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page on using selectors

Comment: No need for jQuery and value is perfectly valid to get the value of textarea.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard jQuery is never _needed_ and I never said so.  It just makes things easier and its how I would solve this problem.  Please do not downvote correct answers becuase of your personal taste.

Comment: @Matt but it's not correct. You *can* get value using `.value` see the link I posted for a solid proof. I won't downvote for jQuery alone.